# PagerTitleStrip overlaps with actual content

Tags: android

I am using A custom viewpager with a PagerTitleStrip, both supported by the android compatibility package. As recommended I use it like this:

```
    <snok.stubefrie.DayPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/strip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>
    </snok.stubefrie.DayPager>
```

However the titlestrip overlaps with the actual content of my viewpager (Both starting at 0,0). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you add views to ViewPager?

When I met the same problem, the cause was to add views with wrong position in my PagerAdapter implementation.

The bad code was like this.

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup pager, int position) {
    View view = createView(position);
    ((ViewPager) pager).addView(view, position);
    return view;
  }
  @Override
  public void destroyItem (ViewGroup pager, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) pager).removeViewAt(position);
  }
  ...
});
```

This code had been working, however, when I began to use PagerTitleStrip, the PagerTitleStrip view became the first child of the ViewPager, hence `addView(view, 0)` broke the internal structure of the ViewPager.

It was fixed by replacing `addView` and `removeView` as below.

- addView(view, position) -> addView(view)
- removeViewAt(position) -> removeView((View) view)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_view, null);


        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view);
        getPageTitle(position);
        return view;
    }
```

Just remove index of addView method. it solve overlapping problem of strip.