# PagerTabStrip position within ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have the following code:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/main_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

and everything gets layouted like it should.

What I want now is that the **PagerTabStrip overlays the ViewPager**.

It should be rendered on top without taking up any layouting space.
Basically the fragments in the ViewPager should start at 0,0 like the PagerTabStrip is doing.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found a way to do this.

In the `onAttachedToWindow` of the PagerTitleStrip, this checks for the parent to be a ViewPager:

```
final ViewParent parent = getParent();
 if (!(parent instanceof ViewPager)) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("PagerTitleStrip must be a direct child of a ViewPager.");
}
```

Therefore this needs to go.

**Solution:**

I solved it now by creating my own custom PagerTitleStrip/PagerTabStrip.
I removed the above behaviour and replaced it by a styleable attribute for my PagerTitleStrip which points to the ViewPager. This is defined in values/attrs.xml like this:

```
<declare-styleable name="PagerTitleStripCustom">
    <attr name="parentViewPager" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And read in the PagerTitleStrip constructor like this:

```
TypedArray types = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.PagerTitleStripCustom, 0, 0);   
pagerID = types.getResourceId(R.styleable.PagerTitleStripCustom_parentViewPager, 0);
```

In the `onAttachedToWindow` we can now check for the mViewPager variable being null and assign it to our pagerID like this:

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    final ViewParent parent = getParent();

    ViewPager pager = null;

    if (pagerID != 0) {
        View test2 = ((View) parent).findViewById(pagerID);
        pager = (ViewPager) test2;
    } else if (pagerID == 0 && (parent instanceof ViewPager)) {
        pager = (ViewPager) parent;
    } else if (pagerID == 0 && !(parent instanceof ViewPager)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("PagerTitleStrip is neither a direct child of a ViewPager nor did you assign the ID of the ViewPager.");
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("PagerTitleStrip: Something went completely wrong.");
    }

    final PagerAdapter adapter = pager.getAdapter();

    pager.setInternalPageChangeListener(mPageListener);
    pager.setOnAdapterChangeListener(mPageListener);
    mPager = pager;
    updateAdapter(mWatchingAdapter != null ? mWatchingAdapter.get() : null, adapter);
}
```

Now the PagerTitleStrip/PagerTabStrip control can be freely positioned in the layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.YOUR.PATH"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/main_pager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStripCustom
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     custom:parentViewPager="@id/main_pager" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is just the quick and dirty proof of concept. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: what is pager id and a here 
pagerID = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.PagerTitleStripCustom_parentViewPager, 0);

Comment: I can guess pager id is int but what about "a" ??

Comment: is it the typed array ?

Comment: and please can you show the whole method onAttachedTowindow() ??

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava: The "a" was an error and should be "types" of course. I also added all the code in the onAttachedToWindow(). The latter part of this method is from the original source code of PagerTitleStrip. Hope this helps.

Comment: I wound up using Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator instead. It's basically the same and I didn't want to create a custom PagerTitleStrip because the internal implementation might change and I didn't want to deal with that in the future...

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/view_pager_container
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/main_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When using a RelativeLayout, if you don't specify where a view should be positioned when it is added, then views are simply added on top of each other in the top-left (or position 0, 0) of the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already tried that. 
I get an exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: PagerTitleStrip must be a direct child of a ViewPager.`
Any other hints?

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought you were trying to specify where the ViewPager and PagerTitleStrip were laid out (and what I said was wrong anyway, PagerTitleStrip does have to be the child of a ViewPager). I didn't realize that you needed to adjust the contents. If you don't mind me asking, why are you trying to adjust the contents of the ViewPager? I guess what I'm trying to get at is, if the contents of your ViewPager actually started at 0, 0, then they would be partially hidden by the PagerTitleStrip. Couldn't you just remove some margins or padding and achieve the same result?

Comment: My PagerTitleStrip is mostly transparent with the labels visible. I want the content to flow beneath it. How would you achieve that with margins and paddings? I think I need to rewrite the layout logic of the ViewPager itself, but couldn't find the right spot in the code yet.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. I don't think that padding or margins would fix that. I did a little research and came across **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9006406/1852466)**. It seems to me that you can achieve what you're trying to do by changing the way in which the PagerAdapter is instantiates items.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I looked at it but couldn't quite figure out how to use it in my example. I'm struggling with this line in the sample provided: `((ViewPager) pager).addView(view, position);` The addView method is not being found. Can you help out?

Comment: I'd be glad too. First, you're overriding the method inside your PagerAdapter object right? Second, are you making sure to call setAdapter and pass it your PagerAdapter? Lastly, try changing `addView(view, position)` to `addView(view, position, layoutParams)` where layoutParams is the Layout Parameters that you provide for your view. If none of those work, can you please post the stack trace and relevant code?