# How to Overlay a PagerTabStrip

Tags: android, imageview, overlay, android-viewpager

I'm creating a simple android project that utilizes a ViewPager and a PagerTabStrip. Each fragment of the ViewPager consists of an ImageView and a ProgressBar. Right now, the ImageView of the fragment does not underlay the PagerTabStrip as I guess the PagerTabStrip has reserved space at the top.

Ideally, I want the ImageView to go underneath the strip as if I had changed the visibility of PagerTabStrip to View.GONE, but with the strip still there to overlay it.

I've tried to adjust the margins of the ImageView and fiddled with the XML parameters by scaling it to "FitXY" but it still doesn't go under the PagerTabStrip. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's the XML code I have below:

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_screen_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/PagerTabStripText"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fbButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fb_button_left_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/download_button_bottom_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/facebookbutton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/miscButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/download_button_bottom_margin"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fbButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/download_button_bottom_margin"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/miscButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bottombar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivityFragment.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's a Screenshot of what it's like now:

```
    With PagerTabStrip: http://i.imgur.com/w1WaF9P 

    Without PagerTabStrip: http://i.imgur.com/Nr2Ny3v
```

The second image was achieved by using a translation animating to move the PagerTabStrip upwards.

Ideally, the ImageView starts from 0,0 in the upper left hand corner and is overlapped by the PagerTabStrip so that when it translates, there isn't a blank white space.

Comment: I had a similar issue. An approach how to solve it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586690/pagertabstrip-position-within-viewpager/20222819#20222819

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you can show MainActivity.xml in full form, I believe there are more View(s) configuration in there.

With the information you have provided, the only reason that could cause this is because you are using RelativeLayout in your MainActivityFragment.xml layout.

Read the [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) document:

> "A Layout where the positions of the children can be described in relation to each other or to the parent."
>
> "Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM."

I will suggest you use ***LinearLayout*** for your fragment that manages its own view without dependency.

Comment: I believe the error is occurring because it is reserving space for the pagertabstrip so the child fragments of the ViewPager are not loading in that space. The problem I'm having is the same one described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586690/pagertabstrip-position-within-viewpager) but there was no solution found there either.

Comment: Not sure if you have tried my suggestion, perhaps you wanna give it a try first. And like I said before, it will be helpful if you provide full layout information.

Comment: Ah, sorry to be unclear, I tried your suggestion but alas the problem is still there. Let me edit the problem to show the entire layout!

Comment: I tried to simulate the problem but no luck. Perhaps I need to look into your MainActivity and ViewPager implementation to trace the real issue behind this. By the way, what is the wording at the top-right-hand corner of the screenshot?